# How does C++ handle a const double& that refers to an int?

Tags: c++, reference

I was working on some template code this morning where I used a `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` to ensure I wasn't creating a reference to the wrong type, as I thought it might be a clearer error message. However when I tried removing the static assert to take a look at the alternative compiler error I was shocked to discover that gcc doesn't even complain when you try to make a const double& referring to an int:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    const double& y = x;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles, and doesn't even warn:

```
$ g++ ~/stuff/badRef.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
$ a.out
5
```

What's going on here? Is this undefined behaviour? If so why doesn't gcc complain? On my machine int is 4 bytes and a double is 8. That means that when printing a double& it should interpret 8 bytes at that address as a double and print it, yet there is actually a 4 byte int at that location.

Very confused. Help!

Comment: What happens when you add `x = 42;` after `const double& y = x;`? It might be curious/unexpected at first sight.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`const double& y = x;` creates a temporary `double` with the value `static_cast<double>(x)`, then binds that temporary to `y`. The lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of `y`.

This is completely legal C++ (03 and 11), hence the lack of warning/error.

Comment: Awesome. I actually figured it out just before your answer by looking at what happens when you increment x, then print y. It didn't change so I thought - "of course! it binds to a temporary!". Also, gcc accepts it with -std=c++98 too, so I'm guessing it's valid C++98 too?

Comment: @Mozza314 : "*I'm guessing it's valid C++98 too?*" Yes; I don't have a copy of that particular standard on hand, but I'm fairly certain that's not one of the things that was added in C++03. Keep in mind, though, that `-std=c++98` actually enforces C++03 rules, not C++98 rules, argument name not withstanding.

Comment: I don't get it... why would you ever do `const double&` when binding to a temporary instead of `const double`?

Comment: @Mehrdad : I don't believe there's any practical use for this, but it _is_ legal.

Comment: @Mehrdad Actually, this can be normal and even happen quite frequently if you have a function that takes a const double& (although it's probably more idiomatic to pass by value in that case).

Comment: @Mozza314 : Indeed, I was referring to the context of doing this with a local (non-argument) variable. Knowing how the behavior is defined in the more common scenarios (e.g. argument passing) is definitely a good thing. :-]

Answer (score 11):

it's well defined and legal. `y` refers to a temporary. consider also when you pass parameters:

```
void foo(const int& p);
foo(3.14);
```

Note also that this is not valid C++ *if the reference is not const*. VS 6 got that wrong and allowed binding a mutable reference to a temporary. This applies only to const references.

Answer (score 2):

`const T&` can bind to a temporary, so `x` is being converted to `double` and the copy is bound to `y`. If you check, you’ll see that `&x != &y`. The reason for this behaviour is to allow passing literals to functions that take their parameters by `const` reference.

Comment: Well, not "copy is stored", `y` binds to the temporary resulting from the conversion, because it's a const lvalue reference.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Replaced “stored in” with “bound to” to—well, if not to clarify, then at least to be pedantically correct. :P

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example for those who think that pointers and references are the same.

```
double const*const y2 = &x;

gives
bad.cpp:7:30: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘const double* const’ in initialization
```

The reason it works for references is explained in the other posts.